# django: filter queryset when 2 fields have same value

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model which has 2 fields like,

```
pickup_station_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
drop_station_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

I want a filter in admin which can filter the queryset based on,

- pickup and drop ids are different
- pickup and drop ids are same

How can I get a queryset based on these conditions?

I mean, something like this,

```
Mymodel.objects.filter(pickup_station_id==drop_station_id)

Mymodel.objects.filter(pickup_station_id!=drop_station_id)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can refer to a ***f**ield* with an [**`F`**-expression <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions). So we can write it like:

```
from django.db.models import F

Mymodel.objects.filter(pickup_station_id=F('drop_station_id'))
```

We can *negate* a ***q**uery* by using a [**`Q`**-object <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q):

```
from django.db.models import F, Q

Mymodel.objects.filter(~Q(pickup_station_id=F('drop_station_id')))
```

Here the tilde (`~`) means we *negate* the condition that the `Q` object represents.